# Settings are missing options and settings after update to Juno

Tags: release-juno, settings, sound, bluetooth

I recently updated from Loki to Juno. I copied my home folder over as is. As I was copying the home folder over, after Juno had installed itself, I marked all the same-name folders to merge and all old files to over-write the new ones.

In Loki I used to be able to control the volume on a per-program basis, now this is missing. 
[image: I used to be able to change or mute specific programs]

Along with that, I can no longer configure Bluetooth media share settings. In the solutions mentioned here I have seen that I should have a tab in the media share section that lets me configure the Bluetooth share.

[image] [image: Apparently it is missing a Bluetooth section]

I've tried to extensively scour this forum for a solution but up until now I haven't found an exact solution and all the similar solutions haven't helped.

As a step I executed 
`sudo apt install switchboard-plug-*` but that helped nothing. It had helped earlier in Loki as a solution for a similar problem.

How do I bring back my missing options?

Comment: You can use `pavucontrol` to change the volume for each app. I don't really know about the rest.